# Distance from a tower

Tags: triangulation, signal-strength

During the triangulation of a cell phone, we need to find out distance of cell phone from tower using signal strength on that phone. Is there any equation to calculate distance between tower and phone by putting signal strength in that equation? If yes, then what is that equation. 
Please help

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, you should refer to some EM textbooks or Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_strength_in_telecommunications). It depends on your frequency band, GSM/3G/4G/5G/etc. It also depends on ground building (settlement) type, ground surface with lots of tall concrete buildings tends to block signal much more aggressively than a rural area with a grass plain.

Practically, you should do some physical measurement yourself because how your signal strength is computed (is it in log scale, linear scale, SNR, etc) does affect many things. Take note of near field effect, that is, when your cellphone is very very close to the station, the signal strength variation behaviour can be very different.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not so simple. At the very list you need to know the transmission power of the base station.